# Print from command line

Tags: printing

How can I print the command line output directly to the printer.

I am using ubuntu server 12.04 and I have to copy files into a shared directory and then download them from a desktop ubuntu distribution to print them.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You didn't say if you'll be printing plain text or PDF. Some systems only support plain text out of the box, so this needs to be covered.

Comment: i dont know why they downvote my answer , just try it .

Comment: @nux +1 All answers are great thanks you all

Comment: @alexis I am clear: I want to print console output. For example ls output directly to the printer

Comment: Oops, indeed you did say and I missed it, sorry!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Mainly there are two default commands:

`lpr` and `lp`

`man lpr` gives the output:

> lpr  submits  files  for  printing. Files named on the command line
>   are
>          sent to the named printer (or the default destination if no destination
>          is  specified).  If  no files are listed on the command-line, lpr reads
>          the print file from the standard input.

`man lp` gives the output:

> lp submits files for printing or alters a pending job. Use  a 
>   filename
>          of "-" to force printing from the standard input.

so easily use the command:

```
lp /path-to-file-to-print
```

Or

```
lpr /path-to-file-to-print
```

Comment: Thank you. Working pretty fine today on 20.04, really useful.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `lp`

For example:

```
man firefox | lp -d printername
```

This will print the man page from firefox to the specified printer

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to use `o fit-to-page` to keep the text on the page a bit better. `man bash | lp -o media=letter -o portrait -o fit-to-page -`, the `-` at the end ensures standard input is read.

Comment: If your printer is default you don't need the `-d` parameter.  On Ubuntu with Unity, the default printer is set by clicking on the Search button then type "print" and it will take you to the right place where the default can be set.  Also, `lp` in the example says you have been around Unix for some time.  `lpr` works the same on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

If you have them installed, another pair of options worth knowing about are

- [enscript](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/enscript.1.html)

and

- [a2ps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/a2ps.1.html)

These are useful for providing numbered pages with headings and optional line-numbers.
You can also use then to print booklet style (e.g. two pages on each side of a sheet)

I use these with Postscript-capable printers but I believe that Ubuntu's print system can rasterize PS for any supported printer.

Comment: this is a nice idea

Comment: Sure beats coding postscript directly.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to find out how the printer is accessed first - `lpstat`will give you that information. If you compare its output across both systems, you can probably tell whether the printer in question has been configured on both of them. `lpstat -p -d` lists all printers with their status and tells which one has been set as default printer.

You can simply pipe your output to the `lp` or `lpr` command then. You may want to insert a filter for pretty-printing or pagination though. There's a good summary of tools at the [debian manual "Highlighting and formatting plain text data"](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch11.en.html#_highlighting_and_formatting_plain_text_data), but I'm usually just using `sed` to highlight prompts and other stuff before sending everything through `a2ps`

Answer (score 2):

To print a .txt file in a  use :

```
command | lpr -P printername -p ( periority from 1 to 100 )
```

Example :

```
ls -l | lpr -P printername -p 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lp` command.

To print the output of a command to the default printer (use `lpstat -d` to see what the default printer is):

```
echo "test" | lp
```

To print to a specific printer (use `lpstat -p | awk '{print $2}'` to list available printer names):

```
echo "test" | lp -d printername
```

To print a file, rather than a command output:

```
lp /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is about how to print from the command line **on a server**, and it sounds like you don't yet have any printers defined on that system. I don't have a system to check on so the following are approximate, but they should give you the general idea:

1. Make sure the CUPS system is installed and running. It provides the
   daemons that will handle your print jobs.
2. Once this is up, you need to set up one or more network printers to
   print to. The usual way to install printers is with the *Printer
   Admin* utility, but you evidently aren't set up to run any GUI
   programs from your server-- just commandline access via ssh. Since
   you already have an Ubuntu desktop system on the same network, I'd
   try copying the contents of the directory `/etc/cups` from the desktop box to the
   server. It should contain all the printer definitions and drivers you need. 
   Check the files for any necessary adjustments (in case your
   set-up mentions user IDs or passwords that differ between the two systems),
   restart `cupsd`, and if you're lucky you'll be able to use `lpr` to
   print from the commandline.

PS. In a pinch, you could install enough X utilities to run the *Print Admin* GUI utility via a remote X connection to your desktop Ubuntu box (log in with `ssh -X`), and define the printers you need. But hopefully this won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control various layout options, fonts, font size, etc. you can use `enscript` as [suggested by RedGrittyBrick](https://askubuntu.com/a/432758/8822).

```
sudo apt install enscript
```

A few details that may be useful:

- The fonts you can use are the ones which have an `.afm` file in `/usr/share/enscript/afm/`
- The font name to use with the `-f` option must be the short name listed as `FontName` in it's .afm file. For example: "ZapfDingbats", not "ITC Zapf Dingbats".
  These names are also listed in the `/usr/share/enscript/afm/font.map` file.
- If you want to see which *monospaced* fonts you have available, you could use something like this:
  `for f in /usr/share/enscript/afm/*.afm; do grep -q '^IsFixedPitch true' "$f" && grep FontName "$f"; done`
- To set the font size, append "@n" to the font name.
- You can get the list of printer names to use for the `-d` or `-P` option with
  `lpstat -p`

Example print command :

```
font=Courier@9
printer=HP-4350

your_command | enscript -P $printer -f $font --tabsize=4

# or for files:
enscript -P $printer -f $font --tabsize=4 $Your_file_to_print
```

There are of course many more options listed with `man enscript`.