# How to print via text-editor (like mousepad) from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, printing, text-editor

While …

```
libreoffice -p mytextfile.txt
```

… works fine and without opening a window (like head-less mode, which is what I want to do), Libreoffice is a very big application to solve such a small task.

Mousepad, gedit and kate don't allow printing from the command line, however.

Does another graphical text-editor allow to do it?

Thanks.

[Edit]
Not a duplicate of the "how to print from command-line" question, since I don't want to print from command-line but start a graphical text-editor from command-line with a given text-file name, and then this graphical text-editor prints the given text-file with the editor's set font and page size settings.

Libreoffice does do that but it's a huge application, and I'm looking for a smaller graphical application doing the same.

Comment: Probably because it is too easy to print a text file from the command line, this is not implemented in the editor itself. See duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432746/print-from-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abiword man pages say you can print from the cli

```
abiword --to=ps --to-name=fd://1 FILENAME | lp
```

I'm not sure if it works headless though. I don't have a printer setup to test

A further look into the cammand shows `abiword` is converting the file to `ps` format saving it to a temporary file and piping it to the `lp` command.

**lp**: `lp` submits files for printing or alters a pending job.  Use a filename of "-" to force printing from the standard input.