# How to print the manual of gzip program

Tags: command-line, bash, manpage, gzip

I am new to Linux and I need to print the manual of gzip program but I am not able to figure it out. I have written the command `man gzip` but I am not sure whether it is reading or printing it.

I am using an Ubuntu server not a desktop version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432746/print-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

`man gzip | lp`

You can even print to pdf:

`sudo apt install cups-pdf`

`man gzip | lp -d PDF`

This works for Triskel.